# Connecting to an Oracle DB from Java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to create a table in an Oracle DB from java. When I run this I get the error

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

invalid arguments in call

I have no idea how to fix this, all my research has come up empty.

```
package Project2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Embedded {

private static String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@query.engr.uconn.edu:1521:BIBCI";
private static Connection conn = null;
private static Statement stmt = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createConnection();
    createTable();
    //insertValue();
    shutdown();
}

private static void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        //Get a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "cse4701", "datamine");
    } catch (Exception except) {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void createTable() {
    //String sql = "CREATE TABLE IG_READY (PatientId VARCHAR(20), APC integer, TP53 integer, KRAS integer, PIK3CA integer, PTEN integer, ATM integer, MUC4 integer, SMAD4 integer, SYNE1 integer, FBXW7 integer, Status integer)";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery("creat table CRCDB.IG_READY (PatientId VARCHAR(20), APC integer, TP53 integer, KRAS integer, PIK3CA integer, PTEN integer, ATM integer, MUC4 integer, SMAD4 integer, SYNE1 integer, FBXW7 integer, Status integer, PRIMARY KEY (PatientId));");
        //stmt.executeQuery("use CRCDB");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void shutdown() {
    try {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        System.out.println(sqlExcept.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the `;` from your SQL string. Additionally: `executeQuery()` is for select statement. To run DDL use `execute()` or `executeUpdate()`. And there is no `;shutdown=true` option for an Oracle JDBC URL. Where in the [Oracle JDBC manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/toc.htm) did you find that?

Comment: Also, creat should be create

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in your sql statement

```
  stmt.executeQuery("creat table CRCDB.IG_READY (PatientId VARCHAR(20), APC integer, TP53 integer, KRAS integer, PIK3CA integer, PTEN integer, ATM integer, MUC4 integer, SMAD4 integer, SYNE1 integer, FBXW7 integer, Status integer, PRIMARY KEY (PatientId));");
```

you mispelled the **"create table"**

Also first execute the stmt with small test table and then create your table

I hope this may help you solving your proplem , If I get any other information ,i will tell you definitely

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed those errors and am now getting the following.ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20905: You are not allowed to do this operation. Insufficient Privileges
ORA-06512: at line 2

invalid arguments in call

Comment: suppose you do not have Privileges to Create tables in the Database. Check the Privileges in oracle database system.

Comment: You really have a user named "CRCDB".. It is the problem I think